# Attempting to run a textbook C# WFA program. Form not displaying result

Tags: c#

im new to using this site, and im also VERY new to programming (freshman for programming school)

Heres the thing, im doing an assignment for class, which is essentially to write this code for a windows form application to calculate some simple stuff. Easy enough, but ive entered the code exactly, and every time i use the 'yes' or 'no' buttons on my form, nothing generates. Ill post my code and also my program being run, and i hope someone might be able to help me. The answer could be obvious, im just still a novice. Thanks in advance!

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LoopingBankBalGUI

{

    partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        double bankBal = 1000;
        const double INT_RATE = 0.04;
        private void yesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            outputLabel.Text += String.Format("Bank balance is {0}\n",
                bankBal.ToString("C"));
            bankBal = bankBal + bankBal * INT_RATE;
        }
        private void noButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            outputLabel.Text = "Have a nice day!";
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

This is a picture of my form itself:

[image]

Comment: Does the text change when you press no? Also as a start remove `outputLabel.Text +=` it should be `outputLabel.Text =`, as you don't want to append to the string every time. Moreover, don't you want to perform the bank balance calculation before printing on the label? `bankBal = bankBal + bankBal * INT_RATE;` should be before `outputLabel.Text = ...`.

Comment: The text does not change. Nothing changes on either when i hit the buttons. Ill make that correction to the outputLabel, i however was following it from the book, as it explains to have '+='. Its always intentionally supposed to be a looping program, as that is the current focus point of the class. If that matters at all, haha.

Comment: I'm assuming you've linked the buttons to their event handlers and the label name correctly? Try calling outputLabel.Refresh() to see if it updates the text after modifying it.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in your `yesButton_Click()` method, to check if it gets called at all?

Comment: Form what I understand, yes. The buttons have the names properly linked to the code, or else the code would give me a warning letting me know that they do not exist in the context. As for the event handlers, could you elaborate a little? Sorry, it sounds dumb, but im still so new to this.

Comment: Would it help you in helping me to post a picture of the textbooks code. Ive attempted to match it. Rather, its right on this link, takes you directly to the page im on. https://books.google.com/books?id=Xy-dBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT243&lpg=PT243&dq=Programming+in+c%23+figure+5-25&source=bl&ots=X4Lb2hrHs-&sig=FQibc_KvXvyaUC_IZw_3tb_vbMA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTnMiw5JDPAhXJ24MKHTbcDFYQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=Programming%20in%20c%23%20figure%205-25&f=false

Comment: Yes, that would be helpful, but its a Textbook, I doubt it will be wrong.

Comment: Posted it on my previous comment.

Comment: My only confusion is, if ive matched the code to the textbook, to the best of my ability, shouldnt it be working? That might sound kind of dumb, but im just really lost as of right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to verify whether the EventHandler method is added to your button click event in the designer.cs file.

```
private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(112, 117);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
```

In the above code please notice the code:

> this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);

The button click event is added this way.

**Update**

The problem you are facing is because [image]

in your code yesButton_Click method is added to the click event when the user first clicks the button. So first time the yesButton_Click method is not called.

So you are not getting the output at first time.

In the InitializeComponent() method you have to attach the yesButton_Click method to the button click event. So that the method is attached when the form is loaded. Then by now if you click in the first time only you will get the result.

Your code should look like this below

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        double bankBal = 1000;
        const double INT_RATE = 0.04;
        private void yesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            outputLabel.Text += String.Format("Bank balance is {0}\n",
                bankBal.ToString("C"));
            bankBal = bankBal + bankBal * INT_RATE;
        }
        private void noButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            outputLabel.Text = "Have a nice day!";
        }        
    }
```

To attach your yesButton_Click and noButton_Click methods to respective buttons you need to go to properties window and select the corresponding methods:

[image]

By doing so method is getting is attached to the button click event when the form is loaded.

Comment: Hm, exactly how would i find this out? From what i see, is the InitializeComponent() supposed to come before my code? The reason i ask is because the textbook is not indicating any of that.

Comment: This actually auto generated code. Just to make your code work double click your button from the designer page, which will take you to the code-behind  with the event handler method. So here you need to put the code.

Comment: Your code seems to be fine. But only the other part .i.e. InitializeComponent() method might not have method attached to the button click event. The text book might have missed this as this will be auto generated when you double click on the button in the designer form.

Comment: Oh goodness, i think that was it. Once I did that, it essentially started working. However, im not running into a situation where, I click it, nothing happens, I click again, and it happens 3 times.

Comment: Sorry I didnt get the other issue you mentioning. But did it solve the earlier issue?

Comment: umm, Sort of. Im kind of confused on how the code now looks. Once making some adjustments, towards the bottom of the code, its added 3 private.void lines with my no_click and yes_click events. However, im struggling to make them BOTH work at the same time. Ill post a picture.

Comment: Alright, small update. With this current configuration (pic posted as gyazo link at end of this comment) ive essentially got it working. The only issue is, its not responding on first click, but on second, and third etc and multiplying faster than its intentional rate. Any thoughts on this? https://gyazo.com/521807e3f80aceb92198e919ab0df923